# Algorithm for binomial coefficient (nCr) in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been given the task to solve this problem:

> There are exactly ten ways of selecting three from five, 12345:
>
> ```
> 123, 124, 125, 134, 135, 145, 234, 235, 245, and 345
> ```
>
> In combinatorics, we use the notation, `5C3 = 10`. In general,
>
> ```
> nCr = n! / r!(n−r)!
> ```
>
> where `r ≤ n`, `n! = n×(n−1)×...×3×2×1`, and `0! = 1`.
>
> It is not until `n = 23`, that a value exceeds one-million: `23C10 =
>   1144066`.
>
> How many, not necessarily distinct, values of `nCr`, for `1 ≤ n ≤ 100`,
>   are greater than one-million?

I have to come up with an algorithm in Ruby to solve that problem, but I don't seem to understand how it's done.

Comment: Does it have to be a "clever" algorithm?  If not, You could always just solve for all of them and count the number of solutions produced that were greater than one million.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by `It is not until n = 23, that a value exceeds one-million: 23C10 = 1144066.`. Where does `10` come from? Do you mean `for some r`? If so, you need to write that.

Comment: @sawa Actually, its copy-pasted from the actual problem page: http://projecteuler.net/problem=53

Comment: @OscarSwanros So what? Are you attributing the unclearness of the question here to the author of the original? The author there is responsible for what is on that page. The moment you cite it here, whatever problem it has here is your responsibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a project Euler problem. You need to apply pascal's triangle to solve this problem.
The pascal triangle is symmetric so we only have to calculate half of it to get the result, this will make your program run faster.

Another way you can cache the previously calculated factorial results and use them in order to avoid unnecessary calculations overload.

```
@@fact_table = []
@@fact_table[0] = 1;
@@fact_table[1] = 1;

for i in (2..100)
  @@fact_table[i] = i * @@fact_table[i-1]
end

def ncr(n, r)
return @@fact_table[n] / (@@fact_table[r] * @@fact_table[n-r])
end

num = 0 
for n in (1..100)
  for r in (1..n)
    if ncr(n, r) > 1000000
      num += 1
    end
  end
end

print "Count exceeding 1 million: ", num, "\n"
```

**Output**

```
Count exceeding 1 million: 4075
```